# Problem when reading a parquet file with the arrow package

Tags: r, parquet

I just started reading/writing parquet files using the arrow package.  I have a 28 M by 35 file, and I can write this file to disk using write_parquet(data, 'file.parquet') - it's about 2.5 Gb.

But when I try to read it using write_arrow('file.parquet'), I get the following error:

```
Error: IOError: Couldn't deserialize thrift: TProtocolException: Exceeded size limit
```

I'm on an intel Mac with 64 Gb of RAM, so I don't think it's a memory problem.

Actually, I just found a workaround: it's a data.table, and if I do:

```
vars = names(data)
write_parquet(data[,..vars], 'file.parquet')
```

I can read the resulting parquet file.  Does anyone have a clue about what's going on?

Thanks very much

sessionInfo():

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.0.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] qs_0.25.1.1       data.table_1.14.3 arrow_6.0.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7          mvtnorm_1.1-3       lattice_0.20-45     png_0.1-7           zoo_1.8-9          
 [6] assertthat_0.2.1    digest_0.6.28       utf8_1.2.2          R6_2.5.1            plyr_1.8.6         
[11] backports_1.4.0     stats4_4.1.2        ggplot2_3.3.5       pillar_1.6.4        rlang_0.4.12       
[16] multcomp_1.4-17     rstudioapi_0.13     rpart_4.1-15        Matrix_1.3-4        checkmate_2.0.0    
[21] splines_4.1.2       stringr_1.4.0       foreign_0.8-81      htmlwidgets_1.5.4   bit_4.0.4          
[26] munsell_0.5.0       compiler_4.1.2      xfun_0.28           pkgconfig_2.0.3     base64enc_0.1-3    
[31] libcoin_1.0-9       htmltools_0.5.2     nnet_7.3-16         tidyselect_1.1.1    tibble_3.1.6       
[36] gridExtra_2.3       htmlTable_2.3.0     coin_1.4-2          Hmisc_4.6-0         codetools_0.2-18   
[41] matrixStats_0.61.0  fansi_0.5.0         crayon_1.4.2        dplyr_1.0.7         MASS_7.3-54        
[46] grid_4.1.2          gtable_0.3.0        lifecycle_1.0.1     DBI_1.1.1           magrittr_2.0.1     
[51] scales_1.1.1        RcppParallel_5.1.4  stringi_1.7.5       latticeExtra_0.6-29 ellipsis_0.3.2     
[56] generics_0.1.1      vctrs_0.3.8         stringfish_0.15.4   sandwich_3.0-1      RApiSerialize_0.1.0
[61] Formula_1.2-4       TH.data_1.1-0       RColorBrewer_1.1-2  tools_4.1.2         bit64_4.0.5        
[66] glue_1.5.0          purrr_0.3.4         jpeg_0.1-9          parallel_4.1.2      fastmap_1.1.0      
[71] survival_3.2-13     colorspace_2.0-2    cluster_2.1.2       knitr_1.36          modeltools_0.2-23
```

Comment: Could you either share the data that is in `data` or share code that generates data that has this problem? 

My naive attempt to replicate this by writing and reading this toy data works for me:

`rows <- 28e6`

`df <- data.frame(
  ints = sample(1:32767, rows, replace = TRUE),
  ints_larger = sample(1:.Machine$integer.max, rows, replace = TRUE),
  strings = sample(letters, rows, replace = TRUE),
  floats = runif(rows),
  factors = as.factor(sample(month.name, rows, replace = TRUE))
)`

`df <- cbind(df, df, df, df, df, df, df)`

`data <- data.table::as.data.table(df)`

Comment: Jon - I'd like to give you access to the datq, but not quite sure how to do it.  I can send it to do as a dropbox or sync.com link.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if it´s your case, but I found out that the [arrow](/questions/tagged/arrow) package (version 8.0.0) cannot deal well with huge amounts of metadata.

If you used tibbles, it´s possible that some of the columns have names* on them. And the parquet tries to store it, but when you try to read the file you can get this 'Exceeded size limit'

- When I say that some columns can have names, I mean that you can find that a column from a tibble can be a nammed vector, something like:

```r
tibble_column = df$col1
names(tibble_column)
#> [1] "name_row1" "name_row2" "name_row3"
```

Note that some R functions, like `predict`, can return a named vector, so you may be adding those names to your columns without even noticing. It´s not always a problem, only when you have huge datasets and usually more than one column that have names.

You can check if this is the case with:
`sapply(df, function(x) length(names(x))`

If you have any value that´s > 0, then this is metadata that the parquet will try to store. Just set df$column = unname(df$column) for those columns and you should be able to save and load the file normally.

Comment: thanks - you might be on to something.  Since I posted that question, I've upgraded computers and now have 120 GB ram.  The problem seems to occur much less frequently.  And yes, as a side-effect of some of my data management, my data at times turns into a tibble.  Thanks for helping